# jQuery and ASP.NET: Execute site code after master page has finished initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, master-pages

I'm having a master page in ASP.Net, which downloads various files via AJAX and does some initialization work for a library, that I'm using, after that. I'm using jQuery's $.when().then syntax for that.

My individual page requires all those settings to be made before executing it's code. Right now, I'm using the $(function () {}) syntax on my page. The problem with this is, that it executes right after the page has rendered, but long before my when.then construct has finished.

Is there way to wait for that construct? Can I somehow fire a custom event from my master page code after initialization, and attach my content page function to that? Or are there even better solutions?

PS: To make it clear, we're talking about client-side-only code here!

Comment: I see you are using JS promises. Can you post the code that is being executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not wrap in the document ready `$(function () {})` but instead in a custom event.

```
$(document).on('mycustom',function () {});
```

THEN trigger that in the `then`

```
$.when().then(something).then(function(){$(document).trigger("mycustom");});
```

Comment: What would you say, is it better to use a custom event, like you suggested, or to use the solution @david provided? Same question to you, David.

Comment: I  like that one also; more a matter of choice but this one specifically addresses the question directly i.e. "custom event after sequence occurs"; you might even have a combination of both.

Comment: Note that ONE difference is that you could subsequently trigger this at a later point, not specific to this question as stated though.

Comment: What about browser compatibility? Is that even a matter here?

Comment: jQuery takes care of that

Comment: Thank you very much for that clarification. I decided to mark this one as the answer because of the reason you already mentioned. This doesn't mean, that I prefer one approach over the other.

Answer (score 2):

In the master page you can set the when/then chain to a variable and continue to chain it in the detail page.  They are, after all, one page client-side.  So as long as the initial chain comes first, you can append to it all you like.

So you might set the first chain to a variable:

```
var eventChain = $.when(/.../).then(/.../);
```

Then in the detail page:

```
eventChain.then(/.../);
```

So the detail page is really just picking up where the master page left off.

Comment: Thank you very much. What do you think about Mark's suggestion? Which is better?

Comment: @AndréR.: Matter of opinion I guess.  Both should do the trick.  There's little difference for the current question, though each approach offers different ways to extend the behavior further if that should be considered.

Comment: You mean because multiple functions could subscribe to that event?

Comment: @AndréR.: That's certainly a benefit of his approach, yes.  You might also want to know whether the operation succeeds or fails.  An event system can "silently fail" if nothing subscribes to that event or nothing throws that event.  Which may be a good thing in some cases, or a bad thing in others.  This approach would "loudly fail" if trying to chain to a variable that wasn't successfully defined.  Up to which what you prefer really.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. What about performance of those two approaches?

Comment: @AndréR.: Negligible, I would imagine.

Comment: Ok. I guess that I'll think a little bit more about both ideas. They both have their charm.